# Mondernist Green Tea Microwave Sponge Cake - Siphon charging

Tags: cake, microwave

I just saw a recipe for microwave sponge cake. The mixture is strained before putting in a siphon and charging. However, there is no mention if that is a NO<sub>2</sub> or a CO<sub>2</sub> cartridge. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 6):

This type of "modernist" microwave sponge cake is usually charged with NO<sub>2</sub>.

One tip, since they can collapse rapidly after cooking: It is best to flip the cakes over when you remove them from the microwave, so that the cup is upside down.  Let them cool a bit that way, then release them from their cup.